# Using files in C++ compared to C

Tags: c, file-io

I want to know how to *create* files and *read* from them in C.

If in C++, I would've just:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ifstream f("data.in");
ofstream g("data.out");
```

and then use it as:

```
f >> whatever; 
g << "whatever";
```

What is the C equivalent to this?

Also if you could recommend me some documentation on C, about what is

`scanf("*here*", &variable)`

"here" and what does it actually means to the variable and why do I have to put "&".. and so on... I'm pretty new in C but I know C++ really well. I know you'll find this question trivial..

Comment: Just about *any* tutorial or book on C should have the information you need. And [here's a good C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) which of course includes a section about [input and output](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io).

Comment: Please search and read tutorials/books. C file I/O is not an esoteric topic, you'll find tons of stuff about it already available on the internetz.

Comment: Really well....

Comment: Read manuals for fopen(), fread(), fwrite(), fprintf().

Comment: ...and scanf().